# Sony Xperia Z5 (E6653) not found by adb

Tags: android, adb, sony-xperia

1) I enabled developer-mode and usb debugging on my device.

2) I downloaded the drivers from sony:

developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/xperia-z5-driver/

3) after hours of research, i followed this tutorial to install these drivers:

www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pBQLVmab1M

4) still not working with adb so after another couple of hours of research I installed the sony companion:

support.sonymobile.com/at/tools/xperia-companion/

5) I restarted my phone by holding volume-up and on/off button. after that the led turns blue and the display remains black. After several times pressing and holding the on/off button the phone starts properly. Now my Win7 searches for a "S1 fastBoot driver" and couldn't find it. Researches about fastboot let me know that I would need this to flash my phone. I don't like to flash my phone so I stopped searching for this missing driver.

6) I restarted my pc and now if I look at the windows device manager there is the device: Sony sa0113 with a childnode named Sony sa0113 ADB Interface Driver with an yellow callsign. Checking out the properties of this gives the information that the device couldn't be started (code 10).

after all that adb devices still doesn't list my device.

what i'm missing?

adb version:

Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.36

Revision 19394af606f6-android

.

sorry for the link format - i'm not allowed to post more than one link ?!?!?

Answer (score 0):

if your first point is correct i.e. usb debugging is enabled then try to download the software using this [link](http://adbdriver.com/)
. it might help you install the drivers if not installed earlier

Comment: This tool also doesn't recognize my Xperia.